# Mostrar años trabajados a partir de un campo fecha en un campo con código JS

Tags: javascript

tengo este código que implementé en un pdf con adobe Acrobat:

var A = this.getField("fecha_ingreso_af_date").value;
var B = new Date().value;

var C = B.getTime() - A.getTime();

this.getField("antiguedad") = (Math.round(C/
(1000*60*60*24)));

es un formulario donde "fecha_de_ingreso_af_date" es un campo fecha y "antiguedad" es otro campo donde se deben mostrar los años trabajados de la resta de la fecha actual a la ingresada en el campo fecha.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.